# Swig and PHP: C function expects enum as argument

Tags: php, c, enums, swig

I have a c function that looks like this:

```
GetCurrentMode(RADIOMODES *radioModes);
```

And both my .h file and swigs .i file contain these enum definition:

```
typedef enum _RADIOMODES { 
        RADIOMODES_NONE     = 0, 
        RADIOMODES_ONE  = 1, 
        RADIOMODES_TWO    = 2, 
} RADIOMODES;
```

GetCurrentMode should set $rcs to the correct mode.
But when I run:

```
$rcs = RADIOMODES_NONE;
GetCurrentMode($rcs);
```

I get these error: 
PHP Fatal error:  Type error in argument 1 of GetCurrentMode. Expected SWIGTYPE_p__RADIOMODES

How do I get swig and php to set $rcs to the correct enum? 
Or how do I get swig to convert enum RADIOMODE to int and back?

SOLVED:
Issue was I needed to add a pointer function after my .h file was defined.

```
%pointer_functions( RADIOMODES, RADIOMODESp )
```

This added several new functions that I can use in PHP.